# "You seem to be using Javascript to avoid clicking the radio button..." error when posting a reason for edit rejection

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

[image]

Please fix as soon as possible. I have seen it using Chrome and Firefox, both used on Windows, if it matters.

Thank you.

Comment: See also [the corresponding bug report on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason).

Comment: I've just got this error too. I had to approve the suggested edit, then edit it out!